# Get 5 random instances from a queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have this view function that renders the first 5 articles in my Articles model

```
def home_page(request):
    qs = Article.objects.all()[:5]
    context = {'article_list': qs}
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

How do i edit it to output any random 5?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389519/django-get-10-random-instances-from-a-queryset-and-order-them-into-a-new-querys/32389589) solution, but it didn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "but it didn't work"--please post the code that didn't work so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to shuffle the entire queryset everytime page loads and slice the first 5 objects in the template. In the views:

```py
ids = [i.id for i in Model.objects.filter(some_field=some_variable)] #list of the queryset's ids
random.shuffle(ids) # shuffle the ids
shuffled = [Model.objects.get(id=i) for i in ids] #map back the shuffled ids to corresponding objects
```

In the template, loop through the five random objects:

`{% for i in shuffled|slice:'5' %}`

Comment: i appreciate your help, but I don't know how I would apply this to my code.

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me

```
from random import sample

def home_page(request):
    id_list = Article.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
    random_profiles_id_list = sample(list(id_list), 5)
    qs = Article.objects.filter(id__in=random_profiles_id_list)
    context = {'article_list': qs}
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```